# Pivot Table - Add this data to data model VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having an issue with my VBA code that creates a pivot with Add this data to data model. i record everything step by step, and here's the code that i recorded.

**Here's part of the code that gives the error:**

```
Sub Pivot_Table_Slide1()
'
' Pivot_Table_Slide1 Macro
'

'
    Range("BJ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Period"
    Range("BJ1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("BJ2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-43]<R2C19+7,""Week 1"",IF(RC[-43]<R2C19+14,""Week 2"",IF(RC[-43]<R2C19+21,""Week 3"",""Week 4"")))"
    Range("BJ2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BJ2:BJ1971")
    Range("BJ2:BJ1971").Select
```

> ```
> Range("BK2").Select
>     Workbooks("IT FIRC2.xlsx").Connections.Add2 _
>         "WorksheetConnection_IT Raw!$A$1:$BJ$1971", "", _
>         "WORKSHEET;D:\Internship\[IT FIRC2.xlsx]IT Raw", "IT Raw!$A$1:$xBJ$1971" _
>         , 7, True, False>
> ```

```
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("WorksheetConnection_IT Raw!$A$1:$BJ$1971"), _
        Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="IT Raw!R2C63", TableName _
        :="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
    Workbooks("IT FIRC2.xlsx").Connections.Add2 _
        "WorksheetConnection_IT Raw!$A$1:$BJ$1971", "", _
        "WORKSHEET;D:\Internship\[IT FIRC2.xlsx]IT Raw", "IT Raw!$A$1:$BJ$1971" _
        , 7, True, False
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("WorksheetConnection_IT Raw!$A$1:$BJ$1971"), _
        Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:= _
        "PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=6
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").CubeFields("[Range].[firc_type]")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").CubeFields.GetMeasure _
        "[Range].[proc_inst_id]", xlSum, "Sum of proc_inst_id"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of proc_inst_id]"), _
        "Sum of proc_inst_id"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").CubeFields("[Range].[Period]")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields( _
        "[Measures].[Sum of proc_inst_id]")
        .Caption = "Distinct Count of proc_inst_id"
        .Function = xlDistinctCount
    End With
    Range("A4:E8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$3:$F$9")
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementLeft 204.75
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").IncrementTop -41.25
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Select
    ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (6)
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.CubeFields("[Range].[firc_type]")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.CubeFields("[Range].[Period]")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ShowAllFieldButtons = False
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Total Cases"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Total Cases"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 10
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Select
    With Selection.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
    Range("F13").Select
End Sub
```

I recorded this Macro, it doesn't work when i tried to use it even in the same workbook that i used.

**Here's the error:**

```
Error : subscript out of range:
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO], Yohanes! Can you please [edit] your question to include the full VBA code that is giving you an error? We'd usually like to see the smallest amount of code possible to reproduce what you're trying to do so we can help. (See [ask] and [mcve])

Comment: Recorded macros are hard to read. Could you clean it up?

Comment: Thank you for including your code Yohanes, can you please [edit] the question again to show us which line of your code is highlighted when you get the `Subscript out of range` error?

Comment: sorry i'm new. i just highlighted the error parts for you. thanks

Comment: Are you currently in [IT FIRC2.xlsx] ? And is there a sheet IT Raw ?

Comment: yessss, there is.